# How do I speed up tap handling on a complex UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an app with a TableView which is contained inside a ScrollView (horizontal pagination).

In each TableView is a custom TableViewCell which has a number of views.

To handle a singular tap on an area within the cell, I add a UITapGestureRecogniser to views within the cell.

Rendering performance is fine. But when I tap, I notice a sizeable delay from the point of tapping, to the point where the selector is called (i.e. I believe most of the time is being spent inside UIKit doing hitTests and finding out which element responds to what).

Is there a way to make this faster? What should I be looking out for that may be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a single tap recognizer to a transparent view that fills the cells contentView, add it last so it's front most in the subViews array, then have it to the hit test for just the views of interest.

That said it would seem the delay comes from some other interaction.

Comment: Initially, I thought so to. I basically constructed a UIAlertView and popped that up and I did notice delays. But subsequent builds it seems to now respond quickly with UIAlertView and the slowdown being somewhere else. The slowdown looks like it's happening in renderInContext: as it takes a "screenshot" of the parent view.